# What instrument is used to detect heavy metals?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, elemental-analysis

If i have blood sample, organ tissue sample or food sample, what analytic technique is used in laboratory to detect the ppm levels of heavy metals? What electronic intrument they use?

Comment: The best is probably Atomic Emission Spectroscopy

Comment: It depends. There is no real answer to such a general question.